# + operator - Java pass by value

Tags: java, operator-keyword

I can't figure out why line 3 prints 1 in this Test class that I wrote.
I thought it would print 2 instead of 1 because I was thinking line 2 has changed the value of x to 2.

Can anyone explain this to me please? Is this to do with java being pass by value or is it some other explanation?

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 1;  // line 1
        System.out.println(x+1); //line 2 prints 2
        System.out.println(x); //line 3 but why does this line prints 1?

    }

}
```

output:

```
2

1
```

Comment: You didn't change the value all you did was print `x+1` if you want the value to change try doing `x++`

Comment: I think you're confusing ```x++``` and ```x+1```. The former is what increments the value of the variable itself, the latter just returns an incremented value but does not actually increment the variable itself.

Comment: yes it looks like I been confusing x++ and x+1. I was comparing it to another test program i created which looks like this:                                                                              int x = 1;
  System.out.println(++x); // prints 2
  System.out.println(x);  // prints 2

Comment: ^ That is another interesting thing about postfix and prefix notation. ```x++``` FIRST returns the value (1) and then increments the variable in memory, making x = 2, whereas ```++x``` first increments the variable in memory, making x = 2, then returns it, thus printing 2 as well, like you noted above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation is simply that `x + 1` doesn't change the value of `x`, but instead returns a completely separate `int` whose value is one greater than `x`.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  returns a complete separate int makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

For Line 2 the output is 2 because x is already 1 and you're adding an other one that makes it 2 but not changing the value of x.
So that is the reason for 1 on line 3 aswell.

Try with x++ on line 2 and see the result on line three.

Answer (score 0):

It is expected.

You are just printing x+1. x+1 does not modify the value of x unless you explicitly assign the new value to x.

if you change the code as below, you will get desired output.

```
x= x+1;
System.out.println(x);
```